# Mercurial hook for rejecting changesets

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I'd like to create a **blacklist.txt** file of changesets that are, well blacklisted from the repository and enforce that these changesets never get pushed to the "master" repo.

Ideally I think I should be installing a server-side hook to handle this, but I've no idea on how to actually create it.  Assuming I have a file called **blacklist.txt** in my hgrc folder that contains:

```
ABCDEF
XYZZY
PLUGH
QWERTY
```

How could I write a "hook" that will reject any push that contains these changeset hashcodes?

Comment: Not that I can help you myself, but on what system are you? A python script would be ideal anyway, if you can handle it.

Comment: How would you know it if changesets are created locally? You can't know which changesets are good/bad